# Flex/mxml: How to display a Number in scientific notation in TextInput box?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

In my Flex application, I have a TextInput box that a user may enter a Number. It comes in as a String, then passes through a NumberFormatter. The result then gets displayed in the TextInput box. This works fine for small numbers.

Large numbers have a problem. For example, if the user enters 100e30 (which is scientific notation for 1x10^32), the TextInput displays:

```
100000000000000000000000000000000
```

when what I really want to display is

```
1.0E32
```

This is how it appears (and is stored) internally in Flash Builder, for example, as viewed using the debugger.

Is there any simple routine in AS3/mxml that can output scientific notation to a TextInput control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var n:Number = 10000000000;
trace(n.toExponential(1));
```

Output :

```
1.0e+10
```

To set it to the text input :

```
textInput.text = n.toExponential(1);
```